# How to divide a date range into sets of 2 months with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set up a logic that counts the number of months in a date range generated with `pd.Timestamp`. I'm able to get the number of months in the date, but I can't figure out how to use Pandas to then take the date range and divide it in sets of 2 months. For example:
If date range is '2020-09-01' - '2021-01-01', it should return `['2020-09-01'-'2020-11-01', '2020-11-01' - '2021-01-01']`. This is my code so far:

```
def get_installs_time(client, appId, startDate, endDate):
    startStamp = pd.Timestamp(startDate)
    endStamp = pd.Timestamp(endDate)
    months = (endStamp.to_period('M') - startStamp.to_period('M'))
```

In the case that the total months in the date range are 3, then the sets should be one of two months and the third month separately.

How can I build on this code and split the date range in sets of 2 months?

Comment: What would be the expected outcome for this date range and N=3 months?

Comment: For the sake of making the question more simple lets just keep it at N=2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still no answer? Here is something that is not pretty but does the job to cut the time range into chunks with a rest IF the start date is provided (as indicated) for the first of the month:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_installs_time(client, appId, startDate, endDate, blockLength):
    s = pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate, freq=str(blockLength)+"MS", closed="left")
    e = (s[1:]-pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D'))
    return list(zip(s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist(), e.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist() + [endDate]))

print(get_installs_time("X", "Y", '2020-03-01', '2021-01-01', 3))
```

Sample output:

```
[('2020-03-01', '2020-05-31'), ('2020-06-01', '2020-08-31'), ('2020-09-01', '2020-11-30'), ('2020-12-01', '2021-01-01')]
```

Comment: I was literally going the `pd.date_range` route before you answered. It helped complete my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping that this attracts an answer by somebody more familiar with pandas functionality. If a better answer surfaces, do not hesitate to change to a more flexible or shorter solution.

Comment: I agree. But after a lot of searching, there's not a lot of examples/answers regarding this type of functionality. Anyone with a better solution would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Oh, and in case you didn't know - you are equally encouraged to [write and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you feel your code better addresses the problem.